# Maven build appears to be overwriting classes when creating jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, jar-with-dependencies

I'm using maven to build a jar-with-dependencies jar.  One of the vendor jar files in the project has similarly named classes with different case.  For example  aM.class and am.class.

When the build creates the "jar-with-dependencies" jar file, only aM.class is present.  am.class appears to have been overwritten or skipped.  The same thing happens for every similarly named classes files.

We have a couple work-arounds, but I'm curious why the maven build is behaving this way.  Thanks

My pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mytest.MyTest</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bloomberglp</groupId>
            <artifactId>blpapi3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hmm this is probably due to the fact that you're compiling on Windows and it is case-insensitive OS. But I'm not sure why the OS would come into play in the unpacking of the dependencies. Try with the latest version of `maven-assembly-plugin` which is 2.6.

Comment: If you really have classes which are named identical and their package is the same how should the classloader handle such thing? Which class will be loaded first ?

Comment: yeah..... this is kind of embarrassing, but I sort of forgot windows isn't case sensitive.  The vendor jar must be generated on Linux/Solaris.   Using the shade plugin instead of the assembly plugin fixes my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same class conflict issue will happen with maven-assembly-plugin, this plugin extracts all dependency jars into raw classes, and group it together.It works in project with less dependencies only, for large project with many dependencies, it will cause Java class name conflict issue, check [here](https://gist.github.com/simonwoo/04b133cb0745e1a0f1d6).

Better way to use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) if you have many jars with potentially could conflict. You can also you [relocating](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) feature in shade plugin to explicitly avoid conflicts

Comment: Thank you... Using the maven-shade-plugin worked for me.